# Working directory of rmarkdown chunk is not where the markdown lives

Tags: r, directory, r-markdown

The rmarkdown directory is where the .Rmd file lives. So the expected output of `getwd()` inside a markdown chunk or in a knitted markdown file should be the file path of the markdown file.

As you can see on the attached image the output of `getwd()` inside a markdown chunk is not as expected. The markdown lies in `C:/temp`, so the output of `getwd()` in the chunk and also in the knitted markdown file should be `C:/temp`. But unexpectedly the output is my default wd of R which is `C:/DefaultWD`. What I am missing? What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: One idea: Are you positive you haven't changed your Global Options to have a different default working directory for Rmd? See the example in the 6th paragraph in section 16.6 [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html) (paragraph starts with "If you use RStudio...").

Comment: Yes I am positive about that. In the options is still `C:/DefaultWD`. The problem exists also for newly created markdown files in other folders. It seems the place of the markdown is irrelevant because the output is always `C:/DefaultWD`.

Comment: Just to make sure since I didn't quite understand your comment: in Global Options > R Markdown the "Evaluate chunks to directory" option is set to "Document" (the standard default for Rmd) and not "Current"?

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right! The setting was somehow changed to "Project". I didn't even knew these options are there. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @aosmith if you want you can post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your R Markdown document isn't looking within the folder where that document is stored, check to make sure your settings in RStudio are set to this.

In RStudio go to Tools > Global Options > R Markdown and the look at the setting for "Evaluate chunks in directory". This is usually "Document" but has two other options. If it is something else, change to "Document" to fix your problem.

Here's an unfortunately ugly screenshot to show the options:
[image]

I read about this in [section 16.6 in the R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/working-directory.html), starting about a quarter of the way down the page.